# Users experiencing crash related to Firestore Pod's internal grpc::ClientAsyncReaderWriter<grpc::ByteBuffer, grpc::ByteBuffer>::Finish

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Users are getting this crash in testing. My first guess was that it's memory-related but I don't have much more to go off of than that. Looking deeper into the code, I thought this might have been a Main Thread issue but it looks like listeners are removed on a background thread, so I'm skeptical that that's the reason.

I thought that removing any active listeners when the app backgrounds and re-adding them when the app foregrounds might negate this crash but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Any advice on how to fix this crash? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Edit: I left the simulator open for long enough and I got this, which is probably the same crash.

[image]

Edit 2: Profiling with the Leaks Instrument didn't turn up anything related to Firestore. It only had 7 small leaks related to Foundation and UIKit after the app closed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was introduced in 0.15.0 – https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2138